# What's the best way to pre-define values for a function?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I wrote a script to help me deploy services to AWS. In my project I work with multiple AWS accounts and multiple services, so I wanted to predefine a few values to make the usage cleaner. Here is how I did it:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

declare -A environments
environments["sandbox"]="aws_sandbox_account_id"
environments["staging"]="aws_staging_account_id"
environments["prod"]="aws_production_account_id"

declare -A services
services["service1"]="api-service-1-ecs-id"
services["service2"]="api-service-2-ecs-id"
services["service3"]="api-service-3-ecs-id"

aws_role=${ASSUMED_ROLE}
service="${services[$1]}"
environment="${environments[$aws_role]}"

echo "deploying ${service} on ${aws_role} with account id ${environment}"
echo "aws ecs update-service --cluster \"arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-2:${environment}:cluster/my-cluster\" --service \"arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-2:${environment}:service/my-cluster/${service}\" --force-new-deployment"
aws ecs update-service --cluster "arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-2:${environment}:cluster/my-cluster" --service "arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-2:${environment}:service/my-cluster/${service}" --force-new-deployment
```

and then I defined the following function

```bsh
deploy_service () {
  bash /path/to/file/script.sh $1
}
```

But I wonder if there is a better way to do this, or a more idiomatic way at least

Comment: It's unclear to me what your intent is

Comment: @Jesse_b to me, with the languages I am used to working with it seems smelly to just define the hashmap like that and use it. I don't know if this is normal in the bash world. My question is basically to understand if there is a better way to handle values and situation like this. Or if hardcoding hashmaps like I did is the standard. Thank you for your replying

Comment: How would you do it in the language you are used to?  Likely there is also a way to do it like that in bash.  IMO it seems like you should be using parameters and getopts for this but that is my opinion as there are likely a dozen acceptable ways to do this.